# If an English qualified team is banned from the champions league, who takes over the vacant spot?

Tags: football, uefa, qualifying

As of the time of this question, there are talks that Manchester City may be banned from the UEFA Champions League 2019-20 competition.

If a top-four English Premier League team is banned, who takes the vacant slot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teams of the English Premier League can earn a maximum of five places between them in the UEFA Champions League, and a maximum of seven places in all European continental competition.

Those places are allocated as follows:

1. Winner of UCL 18-19, if any
2. Winner of UEL 18-19, if any
3. EPL 18-19 #1
4. EPL 18-19 #2
5. EPL 18-19 #3
6. EPL 18-19 #4 (gets dropped to UEL 19-20 if all five previous places are allocated already)

Thus for UCL 19-20, the allocation is currently held by

1. Liverpool *or* Tottenham Hotspur
2. Arsenal *or* Chelsea
3. Manchester City
4. & 5. Liverpool *or* Chelsea *or* Tottenham Hotspur (if not already qualified)
5. ...
6. Arsenal (if not already qualified) (gets dropped to UEL 19-20 if placed here)

If Manchester City is removed, the remaining four teams between them are allocated four places, with the UCL place doubling up, and therefore England's allocation is done.

The exception to this is with Arsenal placed fifth, as they would not otherwise qualify, leaving an unallocated place, but it would be nonsensical to give it to a team ranked lower (e.g. Manchester United in sixth) instead, therefore **Arsenal** would likely go in place either way.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I figured, but I was watching a talkshow where one of the hosts stated that it was entirely POSSIBLE (but not likely), that United can potentially play UCL 19-20...

Comment: The only way to make that happen would be disqualify or ban two of the teams above them in EPL, or disqualify or ban virtually every other club in Europe, otherwise there is zero grounds for them to enter UCL.